# Could not find method jCenter() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am following a course on youtube and tried to create a new gradle project but after the creation I've got the "Could not find method jCenter() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler" I have already tried updating my gradle and JDK (adding gradle to path too) but nothing fixed it, any ideas what could I try to fix my problem?
thanks in advance for your help <3
[a bit of info:
ide: IntelliJ idea; SDK: 15.0.2; java: java version "15.0.2"; gradle: 6.8.2; jdk: 15.0.2]

Comment: JCenter is being discontinued; switch to Maven Central instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to make JCenter one of your repositories in your `build.gradle` file. It should be `jcenter()` with lower-case "c", not `jCenter()`. You can find this line in the `repositories` section of your `build.gradle` file.

However, JFrog is shutting down JCenter completely in May. Try using `mavenCentral()` instead. But the libraries you use might not be available there yet, because JFrog gave extremely short notice. If the dependencies you use are on GitHub, you might have luck adding JitPack as a repository after `mavenCentral()`. Many GitHub projects will automatically work on JitPack without any work on the part of the developers.

```groovy
repositories {
    // jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```